# Creating DataFrames from a TSV file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

Im programing in scala:
I have a TSV file with 13 "attributes". 
My goal is to make a dataframe.
So far i have manage to:
1) make a `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]`

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("file.tsv")
```

and i can split it:

```
rddsplit = rdd.map(_split("\t"))
```

As far as i understand i now i have to make a RDD[ROW] which i can transform into a dataframe with:

```
val df = rddrow.toDF()
```

But how to i transform from rddsplit into RDD[ROW]?

Thanks for the help

Comment: why do you directly read as a csv file with delimiter as tab `\t`.

Comment: I'm Using Scala version 2.11.8

Comment: @CoMacNo The linked duplicate contains information of how to read the TSV directly as a dataframe, without reading as an RDD first and splitting. It can be done directly with one line of code.

Comment: Shankar Koirala: It was just they way i learned to split it, i dont really have a good reason for why i do it exactly that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly read the `TSV` file with `spark csv`

**Spark 2.X**

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
val data = spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv("path to file")
```

**Spark 1.X**

```
val data = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .load("path to file")
```

This gives you dataframe which you can convert to `RDD[ROW]` by simply

```
data.rdd
```

For more about options see [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

Comment: Im having a bit of a hard time understand the option parameters. Delimiter is usually something that tell where the boundary is, but wouldent that be "\t" in a tsv? And what is the "\t" parameter? (Sorry for stupid questions, but im pretty new to this stuff)

Comment: Isn't your data separated by `"\t" ` If so, `option("delimiter", "\t")` is used to set the delemiter as tab and it seperates it with `\t` in deault it is seperated with `,`

Comment: Yeah. So i should be able to run the code under Spark 2.X (if i just choose the right path) without changing anything else. But i get error messages.

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: Error is so long that the cmd dosent show the top part

Comment: make sure you have spark as a SparkSession object

Comment: When running the val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate(), i get the error: <console>:41: error: not found: value SparkSession
       val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

Comment: ok you don't have to make a spark object if you are already in spark-shell

Comment: I managed to get the start of the errors, it says;
General 96. - Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registerd. Enusre you dont have multiple JAR version on the same plugin in the class path...................

Comment: did the error shows on starting on sparl-shell or only after you try to run the code

Comment: after running the val data = spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv("path to file") code

Comment: Than there is something wrong with your setup I guess

Comment: on $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh, edit as `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hive/conf `

Comment: sorry i didnet quite understnad what i was supposed to do there

Comment: Are you on Linux or windows machine ?

Comment: I am on windows10

Comment: Is there a way to send pictures here?

Comment: Sent you an email with it now